# Auto-scroll programmatically on iOS

Tags: ios, scroll

I want to programmatically scroll the UITableView down at a fixed rate.  However, I don't to scroll to a fixed point, I want to scroll the tableView down or up at a fixed rate, until a user cancels it, through some action.

Im currently setting the following code in a timer on repeat every 0.1 seconds.  The scrolling is choppy though.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
let previousOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset.y

if (previousOffset <= (self.tableView.contentSize.height - 20)) {
    tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: previousOffset + 20), animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Make the timer fire faster and add less offset at a time

Comment: that did it.  I wasnt too sure about setting the timer to .006, as I thought it would cause lag.